# how to find certain links on this page?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

please help write the script shorter.

```
import urllib
import pprint

import requests
import bs4


def get_friend_links(url, userName, html):
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
    links = soup.find('div', {'id': 'friends_overview'})
    links2 = links.findAll('a', {'class': 'ipsUserPhotoLink'})
    friendLinks = []
    for el in links2:
        friendLink = el['href']
        friendLinks.append(friendLink)

    pprint.pprint(friendLinks)


url = 'http://forum.saransk.ru/user/20892-ujdyj/'
userName = url.split('/')[-2]
userName = userName.replace('-', '_')
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')

friendLinks = get_friend_links(url, userName, html)
```

it works, but I used too long and record cycle. it is not good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically you could do it in one line:

```
friendLinks = [el['href'] for el in bs4.BeautifulSoup(html).find('div', {'id': 'friends_overview'}).findAll('a', {'class': 'ipsUserPhotoLink'})]
```

But it's a long, hard to read line. Basically, is too much.
A nice middle ground is, in my opinion, just replacing the explicit `for` loop with a list Comprehensions:

```
friendLinks = [el['href'] for el in links2]
```

Or even:

```
friendLinks = [el['href'] for el in links.findAll('a', {'class': 'ipsUserPhotoLink'})]
```

But anything more than that is, in my opinion, overkill and reduces readability.